# Slow index lookup in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the process of improving a cypher query I've realized that the lookup time for the starting node takes from ~200ms to ~500ms (reported from the web admin data browser tool). The lookup takes more time on the first run with worst cases above 1 second.

The query I've been using to test this is as simple as this:

```
START user=node:USERS(id={user_id})
RETURN user.id
```

The graph is quite big: about 28 million user nodes right now (it's the only kind of node). But even in that case the lookup time seems pretty slow.

A benchmark using Neography to query the REST API with a cold graph reports the following for the first hit:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.060000   0.010000   0.070000 (  0.959000)
```

For the subsequent hits the times are under 200ms:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.173000)
```

I have tested the same query inside the neo4j-shell with the following results:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ start n=node:USERS(id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') return n;

+--------------------------------------------+
| n                                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
| Node[31120999]{id:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", ...}  |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row

252 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ start n=node:USERS(id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') return n;

+--------------------------------------------+
| n                                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
| Node[31120999]{id:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", ...}  |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row

34 ms
```

Also, in case it helps:

- Neo version is 1.9.2
- The graph takes about 62GB of disk space (not SSD).
- The max heap size is currently 6GB.
- The machine has 8GB of RAM.

Memory mapping settings are set to the following values (no array properties in the graph):

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=768M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=768M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=1024M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1024M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M
```

Is this lookup time normal for a graph this size? How can it be improved?

Comment: Are all 28M nodes users? Do you use parameters? `START user=node:USERS(id={userid}) RETURN user.id` Otherwise you mostly measure query parsing. Heap is probably a bit low, how much memory does the machine have? You also need half of that at least for memory-mapping. Is that the first run or subsequent runs? You should also not measure the webadmin-ui as this also builds up the textual representation, but rather your real use-case with http-access. What version of Neo4j are you using? Please update the post with that information.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the post. Regarding measuring during the real use case I was trying to remove Ruby out of the equation (using the REST API via neography gem).